# cannot import name 'Secret' from 'haystack.utils

Tags: haystack

I keep getting the error "cannot import name 'Secret' from 'haystack.utils", even when trying just 'haystack.util' it still cannot import 'Secret'

I checked through haystack.ai documentation and it should work im not sure why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Hello!
How did you install haystack? You should install it with `pip install haystack-ai`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me I'm using Haystack 2.0

```
import os
from haystack.utils import Secret
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "Your OpenAI API Key"
llm = OpenAIGenerator(api_key=Secret.from_env_var("OPENAI_API_KEY"))
```